# validate fields that were previously not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i have a selectbox which have some options according to which other options are shown or hidden. for eg user select option A and it will show some fields using 
simply

```
$(element).show();
```

function of jquery.
but the problem is that jquery validation plugin doesn't validates these fields even there are now visible.
I know that it doesn't validate hidden fields but these are visible now but it still not working
here is jquery i am using

```
$('#order_status_form').validate({ignore: ":not(:visible)"});
    $('#order_status_dropbox').change(function(){
        $(this).val()=="shipped"?$('.temp_hidden_field').show():$('.temp_hidden_field').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't answer to this question . I will close this question by now. The problem was with another input element which was left unclosed and was causing problem. 
If you ever encounter problem like this  then check for this error also